# Why this scenario doesn’t count as conveying information through quantum entanglement

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

Supposed you have two electrons entangled on earth, and one is carried on a spaceship and one is left on earth. The spaceship has a program that if the observed x-spin through magnet is up spin it turns left, and if the observed x-spin is down spin it turns right. And right after the measurement the observer on earth measured the x-spin on earth, and observer on earth will know whether the spaceship turn left or right at that instant. I just wonder what’s wrong or missing in my setup?

Comment: Why go quantum here? I have a red card and a blue card. Without looking at them, you take one and put it in your wallet and I take the other and put it my wallet. Neither of us know which color we have.  Then, I fly to Alpha Centauri somewhere and look at my card.  I have red. I instantaneously know that you have blue.  This is how local correlations *work*, and it has nothing to do with quantum mechanics.

Answer (score 1):

You're sharing information, but not conveying it, since you have no agency over its determination. If you're out there and discover that the Romulans have just crossed through the Neutral Zone, then there's no way to convey that alert to Starfleet Headquarters by any such similar setup.